# Passing data from Angular guard to component fails

Tags: javascript, angular, guard

I receive a set of data from a guard, the set of data contains the expected data. My problem is to passing the set of data to my component.

This is my code:

```js
export class UserEditorComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input()
  user = new User();

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  private subscription: Subscription | null = null;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(x => {
      console.log("Incoming data ", x); //the incoming contains the expected data (name & age)
      console.log("Class Field user", this.user); //the field "user" is initialized with default values
      this.user.Name = x.Name;
      this.user.Age = x.Age;
      console.log("Check user ", this.user); //user is undefined      
    });
  }
}
```

What’s wrong here? I look forward to your answers! :-)

Kind regards
Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer relies on the Angular's Component Lifecycle. Let's check what happens accordingly to the lifecycle of your component:

1. You define an Input property that's called "user", initializing it with a new User instance
2. After the constructor, the Input properties receive the value given with the property binding syntax, one by one. Each one of these properties will trigger the ngOnChanges lifecycle's event. In your case, the ngOnChanges will be triggered once after your constructor and immediately before the ngOnInit, as there is only one Input decorated property
3. When property bindings, event bindings and the directives placed on the component's selector have been properly managed, the ngOnInit hook is executed. Here you try to set the "name" and "age" properties on the "user" input property.

Here's is what I guess, relying on the piece of code you posted: you initialize the "user" property in the component, giving it a new User instance, but you lose it when Angular try to initialize it from the outside, immediately after the constructor execution.

In other words, if you have a selector like this:
`<app-user-editor></app-user-editor>`
you have to be sure that a property binding against the "user" property is applied in the parent component, like this:
`<app-user-editor [user]="aUserInstance"></app-user-editor>`

Furthermore, be sure that the value given to the user property is a User instance as expected in the UserEditorComponent: if you send a non-initialized value (undefined) it will trigger the errors that you are seeing in your console logs.

If I may, the initialization you are performing in your UserEditorComponent is useless, as far as it will be overridden by the incoming value. Use this syntax instead:

```
@Input() user!: User;
```

Telling that the user property is an User instance, and that it will be properly initialized after the constructor in some way (the ! character in TypeScript is needed for this) is far enough.

**EDIT**
Checking the code on github, I've seen that the object returned by the Resolver was wrapped into the "user" key, so the x parameter on the resolver's subscription was accessed improperly:

```js
  this.subscribtion = this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(x => {
      this.user.Name = x..user.Name; // Was this.user.Name = x.Name
      this.user.Age = x.user.Age; // Was this.user.Age = x.Age;
    });
  }
```

When a Resolver returns something, it wraps the data in an object with the same key used in the Router config (following, the user's repo Router):

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'user', component: UserComponent,
    children: [
      { 
        path: ':name',
        component: UserEditorComponent,
        resolve: {
          // Data returned by the UserGuard Resolver is placed into the "user" key
          // so, subscribing to the resolver Observable, will return an object with
          // user: {Age: number, Name: string}
          user: UserGuard
        }
      },
    ],
  }
];
```

If you want to check all the improvements made, you can go to the pull request I've made on the user's repo https://github.com/Christoph1972/routing-guard-test/pull/1

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation, really nice! I worked really hard to fix the problem. I tried all mentioned advices, but I can’t resolve the problem. I working on a tutorial series for Angular 8. Maybe do I have a problem with the version? I working with Angular 10/11 and it wouldn’t the first case running into version conflict. I added a simple demo project to Github, It’s maybe better than posting here a lot of code, isn’t it?

https://github.com/Christoph1972/routing-guard-test

Please can you have a look into my code?

I look forward for any advices!

Comment: @Christoph1972 I'm gonna take a look at it

Comment: @Christoph1972 I've made a Pull Request on your repository, you can check the solution there. Anyway, as edited in my answer, the resolver's data was wrapped into the user key, so it was an issue related to the data access. Anyway, I've made some improvements, commenting the code for helping you understanding why I changed such things. More things needed an improvement, but had no more time to spend. Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your work, this was so helpful for me! It was such a little mistake/misunderstanding. In the future I’ll have a better analysis of the console output, it was possible to see the mistake, but I’m not experienced enough at this time. Sorry for that! Why VSC(ESlint) doesn’t complain about: this.User = x, because it’s a type mismatch? Many thanks for the helpful advices, I’ll working on them! Kind Regards to Italy! 